# Jquery submit form then redirect not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have found so many posts about this but I can't get this to work for the life of me. On submit of the form, I need the code to 1) submit the form and 2) redirect to one of the locations inside the case statements. I can get the form to submit without the cases and I can get the form to redirect, but I can't get it to do both. Please tell me I am on the right track but just have code in the wrong spot, I have been staring at this way too long and have hit a roadblock.

```
$("#submitBtn").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var validator = $(this).closest("form").kendoValidator({
            messages: {
                required: function (input) { return getRequiredValidationMessage(input) },
                custom: function (input) { return getInvalidValidationMessage(input) },
            },
            rules: {
                custom: function (input) {
                    var minlength = $(input).attr('data-minlength');
                    var required = $(input).attr('required');
                    if (typeof minlength !== typeof undefined && minlength !== false && ((typeof required !== typeof undefined && required !== false) || $(input).val().length > 0)) {
                        var minlength = $(input).data('minlength');
                        return $(input).val().length >= minlength;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }).data("kendoValidator");
        if (validator !== undefined) {
            if (validator.validate()) {
                $("aspnetForm").submit();

                if ($("aspnetForm").submit()){
                    switch(document.getElementById('interests').value){
                        case "stair-lifts":
                        window.location.href="/Catalog/Online-Catalog-Category/15522/Stair-Lifts";
                        break;

                        case "wheelchair-ramps":
                        window.location.href="/Catalog/Online-Catalog-Category/15521/Ramps";
                        break;

                        case "roll-in-barrier-free-showers":
                        window.location.href="/Catalog/Online-Catalog-Category/15529/Bathroom-Safety";
                        break;

                        case "walk-in-tubs":
                        window.location.href="/Catalog/Online-Catalog-Category/15529/Bathroom-Safety";
                        break;

                        case "patient-lifts-ceiling-lifts":
                        window.location.href="/Catalog/Online-Catalog-Category/15523/Patient-Lift";
                        break;

                        case "wheelchair-lifts":
                        window.location.href="/Catalog/Online-Catalog-Category/15525/Wheelchair--Scooter-Lifts";
                        break;

                        default:
                        window.location.href="/"; // if no selection matches then redirected to home page
                        break;
                    }// end of switch 
                }

            } else {
                $('.k-invalid:first').focus();

                $('.k-invalid').blur(function () { if (this.checkValidity()) { $('.k-invalid:first').focus(); } });
            }
        } else {
            $(this).closest("form").submit();
        }   

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form submission and the page redirect are clashing because in a basic web page, only one of these can occur. When the form submits, it will send the form data via the desired method to the server - typically a `GET` or a `POST`.

Conversely, when that redirect switch statement runs, it will tell the browser to change the page url.

Both of these events will trigger a page change within the browser, but only one can truly happen.

What would help you the most is to submit the form data via an AJAX request and then on completion call the redirect code.

As it looks like you are already using jQuery, check out the [post method here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `.submit()` for this. Since you're using JQuery, you should use an AJAX request, formatted something like this:

```
$("#submitBtn").click(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url : "/your/url", // Whatever URL you're submitting to goes here
        type : "post",
        data : yourData, // Whatever data you're sending goes here
        success : function(data) {
            // Whatever you want to do on success goes here
        }
    });
});
```

You make the switch in URL part of the function the AJAX query executes on success.

Comment: Hmmm that doesn't seem to work with .NET, I'm thinking the only way to do it is to create a hidden field that stores the value then redirects on submit.

Comment: Could you update your post to show what you're currently using? I don't think storing anything in a hidden field will work, because when you do your `.submit()`, it results in the whole page reloading. Any hidden field will end up getting dumped along with the rest of the page.